# Controlar los puntos de datos con Chart Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

Estoy usando chart js, y como requisito me pidieron cambiar los puntos de inicio de la escala x y la escala y, eso ya lo tengo pero me estan pidiendo que si se puede estar cambiando el valor de los "breakpoints" por ejemplo en el eje x empieza 2.5 luego 2.6, 2.8,3.0 etc, pero si ellos quieren hacer que vaya de 2.5 a 3 y 3.5 y asi como sería? estaba viendo documentación pero no lo tengo claro.

Agradezco si alguién sabe si se puede hacer.
Gracias.

Esta es mi config del chart:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: "scatter",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(42, 94, 120, 1)",
              data: {
                labels: chartdata,
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: "SURVEYS MERGED",
                    borderColor: "rgba(42, 94, 120, 1)",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(42, 94, 120, 1)",
                    data: resultnew,
                  },
                ],
              },

              options: {
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [
                    {
                      ticks: {
                         min: 2.5,
                         
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                  yAxes: [
                    {
                      ticks: {
                         min: 2.5,
                        
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
                tooltips: {
                  callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                      var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                      return (
                        label +
                        ": (" +
                        tooltipItem.xLabel +
                        ", " +
                        tooltipItem.yLabel +
                        ")"
                      );
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la propiedad ticks de cada eje, agregar ésta propiedad que determina de cuánto en cuanto saltar los valores

```
stepSize: 0.5
```